# change Azure AD backing from the Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-devops

Currently, my VSO is connected to a Default Azure Active Directory. I've created a new AD and I want to change my VSO account's AD to the new one.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this link from MSDN for details: [Change the Azure Active Directory for your Visual Studio Team Services account](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/change-azure-active-directory-team-services-account)

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow -- links tend to become outdated or disappear over time. Could you update your answer to include the relevant information provided in the link?